# Creating well-separated bins

Tags: variance, binning

I want to distribute my hospital data into 4 tiers (bins) based on the score. Tier 1 (good hospitals) has the highest score and Tier 4 (not so good hospitals) has the lowest score. The tiers can be of any size and there is no problem with that. Importantly, I want the tiers to be **well separated** based on the score, so if this makes the tiers unequal in size that is absolutely fine.

In the example below, I created a percentile rank on the score and then used *pandas.cut()* on the percentile rank to create the 4 tiers. The issue I have is with the tier borders which I think are not well separated. Example (red highlight): DD14 and DD15 have close scores and I don't want them to be in different tiers. Similarly DD24 and DD25 have a similar problem.

Is there a standard statistical approach to address my issue?

Notes:

1. I can round the percentile rank to a whole number to blunt the different and achieve this, but I guess this is not a standard solution, because there could be another scenario where this approach will create different problems in the tier.
2. I'm not tiering directly on the score and use percentile rank instead because I want to normalize the values before tiering. I think this is a standard practice.

**Added below part to answer questions in comments**

The idea is to present hospitals grouped into 4 tiers for selection. Within each tier, I further plan to rank each hospital based on their score or percentile rank. Finally each hospital will have a Tier and a Rank (within the tier).

Business will select hospitals based on their Tier & Rank. More than the Rank, business pay close attention to the Tier. Business will review hospitals in the order of their Tier (T1 hospitals first, then T2 hospitals) and then select hospitals based on other factors. They mostly ignore hospitals in the lower tiers because they are not expected to be good.

Business are not happy that DD14 & DD15 have a very close score but still are in different tiers. They prefer to see DD15 also in T1. My question arises from this business concern.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain the intended use of this separation into tiers?

Comment: If you are looking for large gaps in the percentage scores, you would automatically cut between large groups. In your example, the gap between DD14 and DD15 is one of the largest in your data and only (slightly) exceeded by the gap between DD34 and DD35. Similarly, if you would cut according to original scores, you would hardly find a gap larger than 1, apart from in the top group DD1-DD8. Therefore it would be good to know what you need this separation for (as whuber asked) - maybe there are other ways to achieve your goals than to have big gaps between tiers.

Comment: @Ute It's unclear what you are reading.  The gap between DD14 (score of 15) and DD15 (score of 14) is the *smallest possible* nonzero gap!  The largest gaps occur only at the top three hospitals, so arguably each should be in its own tier with all the rest in the fourth.  If you're focusing on the percentile rank, then don't: these gaps are artifacts of how ties are ranked.

Comment: @whuber, all gaps are so small (apart from the top group) - I seem not to see any that are larger than 1. That was the first thing I thought, too. Then I saw that OP wants to look at gaps between percentage ranks, and yes, you are right, they are artificial. That is why I wrote "you would automatically cut between large groups".

Comment: @whuber and Ute- Thanks for your responses. I have appended information to the question to answer your questions and the intention behind my original question.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to give an objective answer.  If you truly want them "well separated," there appears to be a unique solution: the tiers consist of DD1, then DD2, then DD3-5, then all the rest.  But would that really satisfy your needs, by placing so few hospitals into the acceptable tiers?

Comment: @whuber- May be my ask is unreasonable and I need to leave it there. Thanks for your attention & time.